# Vim process hung on background systematically

Tags: terminal, original-vim

**Edit #1 - I found a plausible reason.**
I suspect that the Vim process got stuck o background whenever I closed a terminal window with Vim still running. I've been careful to :qa Vim and 'logout' the session, and the problem hasn't occurred again. I can infer that probably when I quit the terminal with Vim running, the process itself doesn't get terminated as the terminal alter suggests it should.

**If the problem does occur again in spit of this, I'll update this post.**

---

I've been using Vim, run from the terminal, as my main text editor for quite a while now; sometimes on multiple windows, sometimes with its own tab system, but mostly using the buffer to handle multiple files.

I've come to realize that sometimes, even after :q and quitting the terminal, there is a Vim process hung on background that I can not pinpoint where it comes from. I've tried to reproduce the process forcefully, but it never happens when I want. It happens when it happens, and I only realize bc my computer starts overheating and the fans get going on.

Any Idea why that might be? has this happened to any of you before?
I sincerely don't know what to do.

Here is a screenshot of the last occurrence, it has happen about five times in the last month. I  noticed the overheating, and left the terminal open on purpose so I could demonstrate that all windows were not running processes.

Restarting the system has no apparent influence on it. Running react app servers with npm start, seems to have some influence on it, but it might be wrong correlation since I've meen doing that whilst coding on vim.

[image: Vim hung on background]

Here are the plugins in my .vimrc, I'm not even using YCM.

```
Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'zxqfl/tabnine-vim'
Plugin 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plugin 'dense-analysis/ale'
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Check out [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)